# Adding printer from Gnome 3 on Debian Wheezy, Firewalld not running

Tags: debian, gnome3, printing

I get an error trying to add a printer on Debian Wheezy that FirewallD is not running. I am trying to add a remote printer. There is no firewall on this computer, iptables blocks nothing, and there is no firewalld in the apt repository. Also system-config-printer, which apparently can work around this, is also no longer in apt-get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mirroring error for the Australian Debian Mirror, I only just spotted the md5 checksum error on apt-get update. Using the main debian site worked, and I now have system-config-printer.